# Unity C# CharacterController Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple script attached to a ball model in unity. In a effort to control the ball, I have attempted to mimic [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.SimpleMove.html) example provided by the documentation. The issue I receive is my ball visually rotates half as fast as its physical rotation changes.

Ex: The ball will rotate visually 180 degrees when you make a 360 degree physics rotation.

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float MoveSpeed;
public float RotationSpeed;
CharacterController controller;

void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * RotationSpeed, 0));
    Vector3 forward = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * transform.TransformDirection(transform.forward) * MoveSpeed;

    controller.Move(forward);
}
```

What I would like to accomplish is for the ball to rotate in alignment with the rotation of its physics controls.

Comment: Are you sure the `transform.TransformDirection(transform.forward)` is needed? Doesn't `transform.forward` do the job aswell?

Comment: Well hot dang you solved it. I had been trying to pass it different arguments and i thought that was the problem. Would you like to post that as a answer so I can accept it for ya?

Comment: I cant accept it for 8 minutes, but when i can i'll confirm it. Thanks again

Comment: No thanks needed, glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the `transform.TransformDirection(transform.forward)`, since you are trying to transform the local forward vector of the transform to the forward vector of the same transform.

Just use a simple `transform.forward` instead.